# Raspberry Pi 4 (8 GB) with YOLOV4/YOLOV4-TINY using Tensorflow-lite?

Tags: raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite, yolo, raspberry-pi4, yolov4

What is the best way to run YOLOV4/YOLOV4-TINY on RPI 4 using Tensorflow-lite for object detection? I want to detect/count the no. of people in the room using this followed by detection of items like chair, banana e.t.c?

As far as I know these libraries have MIT license and can be used for educational/commercial purposes, is that correct?

Also, what works better on Rpi 4 with tensorflow lite, is it YOLOv4 or YOLOv4 Tiny or something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried by myself, but YOLOV4-TINY has a weight size around 16-24MB, that's similar to MobileNet float. I think that might be a better fit for small devices like RPi4. Could you give it a try and let us know if it works? :)

> As far as I know these libraries have MIT license and can be used for educational/commercial purposes, is that correct?

TensorFlow and TensorFlow Lite are under Apache License. You can certainly use it for educational and commercial purposes.

Comment: I need to explore MobileNet in that case, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the TFLite Object Detection Raspberry Pi sample. It use EfficientDet-Lite models which works well on Raspberry Pi 4.
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi

If you need to train a custom model, you can use Model Maker. See this notebook to learn more.
https://github.com/khanhlvg/tflite_raspberry_pi/blob/main/object_detection/Train_custom_model_tutorial.ipynb